# Assign Random Number between two value conditionally

Tags: pandas, random

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Prod': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat'], 
    'Line': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'AGE': ['35-44', '20-34', '35-44', '35-44', '45-70', '35-44']})
```

I wish to replace the values in the Age column by integers between two values. So, for example, I wish to replace each value with age range '35-44' by a random integer between 35-44.

I tried:

```
df.loc[df["AGE"]== '35-44', 'AGE'] = random.randint(35, 44)
```

But it picks the same value for each row. I would like it to randomly pick a different value for each row.

I get:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Prod': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat'], 
    'Line': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'AGE': ['38', '20-34', '38', '38', '45-70', '38']})
```

But I would like to get something like the following. I don't much care about how the values are distributed as long as they are in the range that I assign

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Prod': ['abc', 'qrt', 'xyz', 'xam', 'asc', 'yat'], 
    'Line': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'AGE': ['36', '20-34', '39', '38', '45-70', '45']})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
random.randint(35, 44)
```

Produces a *single* random value making the statement analogous to:

```
df.loc[df["AGE"]== '35-44', 'AGE'] = 38  # some constant
```

---

We need a collection of values that is the same length as the values to fill. We can use [`np.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) instead:

```
import numpy as np

m = df["AGE"] == '35-44'
df.loc[m, 'AGE'] = np.random.randint(35, 44, m.sum())
```

([`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) is used to "count" the number of `True` values in the Series since `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`)

`df`:

```
  Prod      Line    AGE
0  abc  Revenues     40
1  qrt       EBT  20-34
2  xyz  Expenses     41
3  xam  Revenues     35
4  asc       EBT  45-70
5  yat  Expenses     36
```

*Reproducible with `np.random.seed(26)`

---

Naturally, using the filter on both sides of the expression with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) would also work:

```
import random

m = df["AGE"] == '35-44'
df.loc[m, 'AGE'] = df.loc[m, 'AGE'].apply(lambda _: random.randint(35, 44))
```

`df`:

```
  Prod      Line    AGE
0  abc  Revenues     36
1  qrt       EBT  20-34
2  xyz  Expenses     37
3  xam  Revenues     43
4  asc       EBT  45-70
5  yat  Expenses     44
```

*Reproducible with `random.seed(28)`